# jQuery: How to remove all classes except the last class from an element

Tags: jquery

I have several spans that have some classes, and I don't know how many classes each will have, typically between two and four.  I want to drop all classes except the last class (which corresponds to a person's last name).  Here's the html markup:

```
<span class="author-page-author-name"><span class="author-name-Enver author-name-Ali author-name-Akova">Enver Ali Akova</span></span>
```

So the above should turn into:

```
<span class="author-page-author-name"><span class="author-name-Akova">Enver Ali Akova</span></span>
```

PS. I have several .author-page-author-name's on the page so it would need to apply to multiple authors, basically removing classes that correspond to their first and middle names but keeping classes corresponding to their last names.

Thanks for any insight anyone can add!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of `.split()` and `.pop()`;

```
$('.author-page-author-name span').attr("class",function() {
  return $(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop()
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.author-page-author-name span').attr("class",function() {
  return $(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="author-page-author-name">
<span class="author-name-Enver author-name-Ali author-name-Akova">Enver Ali Akova</span></span>
```

Comment: @PatrickMan consider marking it as answered if you question is solved